# Invoking Custom Class at Server Startup to Set System Properties in WSO2

Tags: server, wso2, wso2-esb, wso2-integration-studio, wso2-micro-integrator

I am working on a project using WSO2 Micro Integrator 4.2, and I need to invoke a custom class during the server startup process. This class will be responsible for setting specific system properties. I want to ensure that this class is executed only during server startup and not by calling it through APIs.

How to achieve this in WSO2? Any example code or configuration files would be greatly appreciated.

I want my custom class to be executed at the server starting time and I can access those system properties in my api flows. I don't want to call the class within a API to invoke that class.